# Splitting date column in Pandas

Tags: python

I want to resolve below splitting Date into Year/Month/Week/Day.

```
    retail_df2[['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day']] = retail_df2.InvoiceDate.apply(lambda x: [x. year, x.month, x. week, x. day])
```

Comment: My original script is below, and i am trying to replicate this logic in above code.

    retail_df2['Year'] = retail_df2.InvoiceDate.dt.year
    retail_df2['Month'] = retail_df2.InvoiceDate.dt.month
    retail_df2['Week'] = retail_df2.InvoiceDate.dt.week
    retail_df2['Day'] = retail_df2.InvoiceDate.dt.day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def fun(x):
    """
    asumming that the elements of column (x) has 
    atributes x.year, x.month, x.week, x.day"""
    
    return x.year, x.month, x.week, x.day   

retail_df2['Year'], retail_df2['Month'], retail_df2['Week'], retail_df2['Day'] = zip(*retail_df2['InvoiceDate'].apply(fun))
```